# Is there an R function for combining two replicate site columns in a table to show presence absence of species?

Tags: r

I have the following DF (example data, my actual data set is 96 columns):

```
   class   X1A X1B X2A X2B X3A X3B X4A X4B X5A X5B X6A X6B
1       A     0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
2       B     1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1
3       C     0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
4       D     0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
5       A     0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
6       B     0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1
7       C     0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
8       D     0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
9       A     0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
10      B     1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1
11      C     0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
12      D     0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
```

Class denotes the phylogenic class of the organism (each replicate of the letter is a different species but members of the same class). 1A and 1B are samples from the same site. I want to combine the two presence/absence data (1/0 respectively) from each two samples from every site and add up the number of "presences" for the class across that site. so that my df now looks something like this:

```
  Sample Class  Number of Species Present  
      1     A     3  
      1     B     2  
      1     C     0  
      1     D     1  
      2     A     2  
      2     B     3  
      2     C     3  
      2     D     3
```

For example,
in the original df you see that Class C species are not present in sample 2A at all but each species of class C is present in sample 2B. So the output df records Species C as present 3 times in sample 2. Furthermore, Class B has 3 different species occur in 2A  and in 2B but because they are replicates of  the output df records sample 2 as having 3 Class B species present.

Any help would be appreactiated as I'm stumped!

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, Jarrod, welcome to SO. Please always post the actual code for your data or example data in the body of your questions. You can use `dput(your_data)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to format your initial `df` a bit (since your colnames actually contain more information than just being a "name").

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data %>% pivot_longer(-class, names_to = 'site', values_to = 'presence') %>%
  mutate(sample=substr(site,1,1)) %>% 
  mutate(site = substr(site, 2,2))

d %>% group_by(class,sample) %>% 
  summarise(presence = sum(presence)) %>% arrange(sample)
```

which results in:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   class [4]
   class sample presence
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 A     1             3
 2 B     1             4
 3 C     1             0
 4 D     1             1
 5 A     2             4
 6 B     2             6
 7 C     2             3
 8 D     2             3
 9 A     3             0
10 B     3             0
```

Here is the data with `dput()`:

```
structure(list(class = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"A", "B", "C", "D"), `1A` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0), `1B` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), `2A` = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), `2B` = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `3A` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1), `3B` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `4A` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), `4B` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), `5A` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), `5B` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), `6A` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `6B` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `1A` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1B` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2A` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2B` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3A` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3B` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `4A` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `4B` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5A` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5B` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `6A` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `6B` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Code**

```
df %>%
#long format with column for sample and species
  pivot_longer(-class,
               names_pattern = "(\\d*)([A-Z]*)",
               names_to = c("sample", "species")) %>%
#creating two columns (for each species one) 
  pivot_wider(c(class, sample),
              names_from = species, 
              values_from = value,
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(c(A, B)) %>%
#creating a presence column - 1 when any species (column  A and B) is presence
  mutate(presence = ifelse(A  == 1 | B == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
#sum prescence by sample and class
  group_by(sample, class) %>%
  summarise(Number = sum(presence))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   sample [6]
   sample class Number
   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
 1 1      A          3
 2 1      B          2
 3 1      C          0
 4 1      D          1
 5 2      A          2
 6 2      B          3
 7 2      C          3
 8 2      D          3
 9 3      A          0
10 3      B          0
# ... with 14 more rows
```